# Favicon : Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace

Tags: html, favicon

This is the head of my Javascript in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Simon>nan
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /
```

HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have errors on your code. I think you forget to add the head complete.

You need to remove the "nan" string next to meta autor tag and you forget to close the icon tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Simon">
  <link rel=" icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<html>
```